# How does sync() work?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I checked `man 2 sync`

It shows `sync` and `syncfs`

```
   void sync(void);

   void syncfs(int fd);
```

`syncfs` is easy to understand. An fd is given and the data of that fd is written completely to underlying file systems.

What is it with `sync`?

```
sync() causes all buffered modifications to file metadata and data to be written to the underlying file systems.
```

Is it that all the buffers in the system are written to fs? or is it that all the files that are opened by this process are written to fs? I didnot quite understand `"buffered modifications to file metadata"`

Comment: syncfs actually synchronises the `file system` containing the file referred to by fd, rather than just that file, as indicated by e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/syncfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you issue a `write`, `send`, write to file-backed mappings or similar things the kernel is not forced to flush that data straight to persistent storage, the underlying network stack, etc... This buffering is done for performance reasons.

`sync` instructs the kernel to do exactly this. Empty all buffers.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I kind of understood this from makefile. My query was what is "Empty all buffers."? All buffers in system or buffers handled by process?

Comment: @Manty All buffers currently handled by the kernel. This system call was introduced in order to be able to recover from system crashes with minimal loss to data if called regularly.

Comment: Oh. So in case of kernel panic, this is automatically called? Also, Now I infer that syncfs() is better than sync() wrt load on the system. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Manty In case of a kernel panic nothing will happen - the kernel shuts down. `syncfs` allows you some selection of what to sync to persistent storage. In terms of system load it is a lot better, yes.

Comment: I think "empty all buffers" is wrong (or to imprecise). It writes out the content of the "file cache", which is kernel controlled, but doesn't empty, clear or free any of it. Subsequent reads will still come from the cache.

Comment: @Manty "All buffers in system or buffers handled by process?". It will only write out the content cached by the kernel. If you have a process using buffered "stdio.h" streams, for example, they will not be touched by a `sync()` call. The buffers will have to be flushed with `fflush()`.

Comment: @tristopia This use case is close to the one I am using in my application. I am redirecting stdio and stderr to my custom file. So i should be using fflush() in my case. Bdw i always thought stdout and stderr are managed by kernel. No? who maintains it?

Comment: stdio.h routines (`fprintf`, `fgets` etc.) are part of the standard C library. It uses buffers that are handled by the code in the library (`libc.so` on Unix and Linux) and reside in the processes memory. There are functions to manage these buffers, like `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()`. Ultimatively, the functions will use kernel API primitives like `write()`, `read()`, `open()`, `close()`, `ioctl()` etc. `sync()` belongs to this kernel API. `fflush()` is not. It is library code and works only on the library managed buffers.

Comment: By default, FILE * streams are opened with a one memory page buffer (4K) and uses line mode. This means that when the fprintf() encounters a line feed in the output it flushes the buffer automatically. That's why most of the time one doesn't need to call `fflush()` that often.

Comment: @tristopia  "It will only write out the content cached by the kernel." - Can you suggest an example? If I am thinking from application perspective(including libraries), all buffers that my app(and libraries) allocates will not be of kernel right? Also, if i am accessing buffers through fread and fwrite, the data is streamed IO i believe and hence sync would not work in all the above cases. Also i request if you can post a different answer as it talks about different important points. Thank you.

Comment: The kernel caches any file access in your system. The background services, the graphical environment, your music player running in background etc. access files and the kernel will cache all these file accesses. When any of these process modifies a file, the modification will only be done on that memory copy. The kernel will after a certain time write out the changes to the filesystem, but nobody knows when the kernel will do it. The call to `sync()` will force the rewrite of all these modified caches regardless of which process modified the page.

Comment: In the case of `fflush` the data held in it will be written out by a call of the `write` syscall, but this written data will land in the file cache. It is even unlikely that it will land on the disk anytime soon. I invite you to read this blog entry which explains all this stuff in detail http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/